# when was -u switch added to git-push?

Tags: git

In which version of git was the -u switch added?

The University of Central Flordia's eustis server is running 1.5.4.3. I'm getting the following error when attempting to use the -u option on git-push.

```
$ git push -u origin master
error: unknown switch `u'
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1.7.0.

```
$ git log -S-u Documentation/git-push.txt
commit e9fcd1e2121100d43d2d212eb6c6f1fc82aade1d
Author: Ilari Liusvaara <ilari.liusvaara@elisanet.fi>
Date:   Sat Jan 16 23:45:31 2010 +0200

    Add push --set-upstream

    Frequent complaint is lack of easy way to set up upstream (tracking)
    references for git pull to work as part of push command. So add switch
    --set-upstream (-u) to do just that.

...
$ git tag --contains e9fcd1e
v1.7.0-rc0~71^2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find things like this, easiest way is to grep the release notes ( either through a cloned git source or you can use the advanced search features of github and search one of the git mirrors).

Release 1.7.0 release notes has the following:

> "git push" learned "git push --set-upstream origin forker:forkee" that
>   lets you configure your "forker" branch to later pull from "forkee"
>   branch at "origin".

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.0.txt